# Put result from mysql_query in php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to get some results from the MySQL database and put them in a array like this:

```
array("value2", "value2", "value3");
```

I have tried this:

```
$models = array();
$getmodels = mysql_query("select model from cars");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($getmodels)) {
    $models[$res['model']];
}
```

This does not work, when i check if the model is in array i get FALSE:

```
in_array($_REQUEST['model'], $models))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were supposed to give each key a value, not turning the values into the keys. Try this:

```
$models = array();
$getmodels = mysql_query("select model from cars");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmodels)) {
    $models[] = $res['model'];
}
```

This will create an array with numeric index. Each key will have the car's model as the value.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_fetch_array()` if you do not use the number indizes but `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. But even better would be to use `mysqli_*()` instead of `mysql_*()`.