# MySQL output to php echo

Tags: php, mysql

I made this MySQL query to sum a column then i did echo $rake and i got the output :  Resource id #13

It will be highly appreciated if anyone can assist me with this

```
<?php 
        $rake = mysql_query("select sum(value) as RakeSum from rakeitems");

        echo $rake;

?>
```

Did i forget something after the query? I am not very good at mysql so im unsure. Any help will be nice :) I have tried changing the query up.

And what does as do in the query, "as RakeSum" what does that mean?

Comment: as RakeSum means that when you go to see the data, it's column name will be `RakeSum`. otherwise the name would be `sum(value)` as the column. You can run this in the mysql database to see (with and without `as`)

Comment: Ok thanks could yo fix the resource id #13 output im getting?

Comment: It's a resource, meaning you need to run it through `mysql_fetch_assoc`  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785401/put-result-from-mysql-query-in-php-array

Comment: It sounds like you are just learning php/mysql, then dont' waste time on mysql_* dangerous and removed in php 7. Learn PDO

Answer (score 0):

Here `$rake` is a resource 
 give a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to know how to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get data from a resource